# Mosel Iterations - Clean Memory

Tags: memory, mosel

I am trying to optimize a model for 250 different price scenarios using a loop. At the beginning, XPRESS can handle 5 scenarios within a minute, but then the memory starts to increase, the runs get slower and after 50 scenarios, XPRESS starts to solve a single scenario in 5 minutes. How can I clean the memory at the end of each iteration?

Thank you very much,

Ahu

Comment: Any code samples?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but could you wrap the optimization within a procedure and loop through the scenarios?

From slightly dated [docs](http://brblog.typepad.com/files/mosel_lang.pdf):

> 2.9.3 Local declarations
>
> Several declaration blocks may be used in a subroutine and all
>   identifiers declared are local to this subroutine.
>   This means that all of these symbols exist only in the scope of the
>   subroutine (i.e. between the declaration and the end-procedure or
>   end-function statement) and **all of the resource they use is released
>   once the subroutine terminates** its execution unless they are
>   referenced outside of the routine (e.g. member of a set defined
>   globally). As a consequence, active constraints (linctr that are not
>   just linear expressions) declared inside a subroutine and the
>   variables they employ are still effective after the termination of the
>   subroutine (because they are part of the current problem) even if the
>   symbols used to name the related objects are not defined any more.
>   Note also that a local declaration may hide a global symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'dellcell' command to delete dynamic arrays of mpvars.

dellcell(myVar)

Also, you can use a mpproblem variable

```
declarations
   MyProblem: mpprob
end-declarations


forall(p in Prices) do
    with MyProblem do
        ! create mpvar
        ! create constraints
        ! solve problem
        reset(MyProblem)
        delcell(MyVar1)
        delcell(MyVar2)
        ! etc
    end-do
end-do
```